# Barplot: plot range of values

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to plot the range of values of a variable among years. 
I have done it using plot points, however points make viewing difficult. Therefore I would like to use bars. Does anyone know how to do it?

I put below the code of an example about what I want, but using plot points.

```
Degrees <- c(20, 19, 18, 20, 19, 18, 17, 10, 9,  8)
Year <- c("85", "85", "85", "86", "86", "86", "86", "87", "87", "87")
df <- data.frame (Degrees=Degrees, Year=Year)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(Year, Degrees))
p + geom_point()
```

Comment: I assume you don't want boxplot(Degrees~Year, data=df).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programmatically find min and max values per year and give columns proper names:

```
year_min <- setNames(aggregate(df$Degrees, by = list(df$Year), min), c("Year", "Degrees"))
year_max <- setNames(aggregate(df$Degrees, by = list(df$Year), max), c("Year", "Degrees"))
```

Concatenate them into a dataframe:

```
df_merge <- rbind(year_min, year_max)
```

Then do a box plot

```
boxplot(Degrees~Year, data=df_merge)
```

[image: Boxplot with min and max values per year only]

Answer (score 1):

Or perhaps something like this?

```
ggplot(df, aes(Year, Degrees)) +
     stat_summary(fun.y = mean, fun.ymin = min, fun.ymax = max, col = 'red')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I think rectangules help more in visualization.

Answer (score -1):

I think you might want a boxplot, i.e. something to depict the range of values for a given year, instead of a barplot...

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(Year, Degrees))
p + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

A bar plot would look like this (the values get summed by year):

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(Year, Degrees))
p + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: The OP did not specifically ask for a box plot.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted something similar to the answer from @rafaelvalle